XCode takes 20m-30m to build and run Flutter app from VSCode
I am building a flutter app which uses Firebase Firestore. I am getting very slow build times (on a Macbook Pro 16in i9 16GB SSD) so I have followed
https://joshuamdeguzman.com/blog/improve-flutter-firestore-build/#:~:text=The%20issue%20is%20caused%20by,iOS%20SDK%20solves%20this%20problem.
and added
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  
  # https://joshuamdeguzman.com/blog/improve-flutter-firestore-build/#:~:text=The%20issue%20is%20caused%20by,iOS%20SDK%20solves%20this%20problem.
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.24.0'
end

This build the XCode project fast but when I press on app icon to open the app I get the following error in XCode
    dyld`:
    0x1c7bfdcd0 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x1c7bfdcd4 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1c7bfdcd8 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1c7bfdcf8               ; <+40>
    0x1c7bfdcdc <+12>: pacibsp 
    0x1c7bfdce0 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1c7bfdce4 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1c7bfdce8 <+24>: bl     0x1c7b95618               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1c7bfdcec <+28>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1c7bfdcf0 <+32>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x1c7bfdcf4 <+36>: retab  
    0x1c7bfdcf8 <+40>: ret

    #0  0x00000001c7bfdcd8 in __abort_with_payload ()

after which there is a black screen and I have to terminate the app. Could someone please help me resolve this issue?
Thanks
